# Retrieve MySQL Image Blob in HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, blob

for my web app Im using C# WebService, JavaScript, jQuery and JavaScript I upload an image into a table with this structure:

```
Id | FileName | ContentType | Content
 1 |Tulips.jpg| image/jpeg  | (Binary/Image)
```

I want to show this information in a HTML page, at the moment my HTML show this information:

```
2 | Tulips.jpg | image/jpeg | System.Byte[]
```

I want to show the image instead of System.Byte[], how can I do that?
This is all my code:

C# class

public class Imagenes
{
    public Imagenes() { }

```
public Imagenes(int id, string fileName, string type, string content)
{
    Id = id;
    FileName = fileName;
    Type = type;
    Content = content;
}
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FileName { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public string Content { get; set; }       
}
```

DataBase Class

Here is no problem is just a Select * from.

WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public string Image(int id)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = conn.consultImg("tbl_images", id);
    Imagenes img;        
    List<Imagenes> list = new List<Imagenes>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        img = new Imagenes();
        img.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Id"]);
        img.FileName = dt.Rows[i]["FileName"].ToString();
        img.Type = dt.Rows[i]["ContentType"].ToString();
        img.Content = dt.Rows[i]["Content"].ToString();
        list.Add(img);
        img = null;
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string lines = js.Serialize(list);
    return lines;
}
```

And JavaScript code:

```
var id = $('#Id').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ws_MyWebService.asmx/Image", 
    data: '{"id":' + id + '}', 
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    timeout: 60000,
    error: function (xhr) {

    },
    success: function (data) {
        var aRC = JSON.parse(data.d);
        var lines = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < aRC.length; i++) {
            var id = aRC[i].Id;
            var fname = aRC[i].FileName;
            var type = aRC[i].Type;
            var content = aRC[i].Content;

            lines += '<p>' + id + '</p>';
            lines += '<p>' + fname + '</p>';
            lines += '<p>' + type + '</p>';
            lines += '<p>' + content + '</p>';

        }
        $('#MyDiv').html(lines);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make two changes on your original code:

**WebMethod**

```
//Change this line
img.Content = dt.Rows[i]["Content"].ToString();

//Use this instead
img.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(Serialize(dt.Rows[i]["Content"]));
```

**Extra Method**

```
public static byte[] Serialize(object obj)
{
  var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  var ms = new MemoryStream();
  binaryFormatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
  return ms.ToArray();
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//Replace this line
lines += '<p>' + content + '</p>';

//With this one
line += '<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + content + '" /></p>';
```

You can set the **MaxJsonLength** property on your `Web.config`:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: img.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(dt.Rows[i]["Content"]); this show me an error: "cannot convert from object to byte[]"

Comment: Where should I put the Extra Method?

Comment: Just for testing purposes, put it in the same file where resides your web method

Comment: I put in before my  webmethod but nothing happen (Its a .asmx file)

Comment: Yes, cannot convert from object to byte[] still there

Comment: Didi you modify this line too right?: `img.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(Serialize(dt.Rows[i]["Content"]));`  (it calls `Serialize` now)

Comment: My fault, now works but when I execute the webmethod I get this error: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property."

Comment: I have to use <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/> in web.Config, but I dont know how to add this, my web.Config have this

Comment: <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" /> And doesnt recognize maxJsonLenght

Comment: Now work! But the image is displayed like if doesn't exist

Comment: There was a typo on my answer...this is the fixed javascript line: `line += '<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + content + '" /></p>';`

Comment: You can do the following exercise...upload a tiny image to your MySQL database...also check in this site if the base64 string is correct based on that image: https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: With tiny image doesnt work, and in base64-image.de I get a different base64 string, no too much different but changes a couple of things, what should I do?

Comment: Can you post those values on your question, in order to check the differences?

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/yrF0A8Vw  whit the text from base64-image.de the image is displayed correctly! So the problem is the base64 string from my app

Comment: It seems that your binary file is saved in the databasewith an extra `i` character....from your app string this `AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAPAQAAAGkBAAAC` is the  `i` character and the rest is the file(you can check in here https://www.base64decode.org/ )....make a similar test with another small image to see if it get stored with the extra character....

Comment: Hey bro! I create a C# method to display the image, and it showed correctly! so the problem is with the methods in my question and your answer.

Comment: That makes sense...then the blob is stored right in the database....maybe if we join your method with the answer, we could make the whole thing works

Comment: Can I contact you in another form? I speak spanish and I think that can help a lot to explain all in spanish, however let me add you a pastebin with all the methods used to do this.

Comment: You speak, Spanish?...LOL, me too...just write me an email at robert.rozas.n@gmail.com, and I'll check it on lunch...Cheers

Comment: Yes, I saw your profile and I see that, ready! thanks for your help buddy.

Comment: @Hackerman can you please help me with a similar question i am trying to implement your approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821094/entityframework-reading-blob-data-into-html-img

Answer (score 0):

You could return a base64 encoded string representation of the image.

Using the [Convert.ToBase64String Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Where you output the image you would then have:

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <!-- base64 string here -->" />
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that? I try with this Convert.ToBase64String(dt.Rows[i]["Content"]); but this shows me an error: cannot convert from object to byte[]